# Data insertion not happening to mysql db using python3.8

Tags: python-3.x, phpmyadmin

I am not able to insert data to my MySQL db.
getting the below message. Please suggest.

> > > cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO dht11serial (humidity,temperature) VALUES (%s,%s)""", 70.0,32.0)

It gives the below:

<generator object MySQLCursor._execute_iter at 0x03A62D10>

FYI i am using python 3.8.3

Please find the entire script:

import serial

import MySQLdb

import time

dbConn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","dbserial") or die ("could not connect to database")

#open a cursor to the database

cursor = dbConn.cursor()

device = 'COM18' #this will have to be changed to the serial port you are using

try:

print "Trying...",device

arduino = serial.Serial(device, 9600)

except:

print "Failed to connect on",device

while True:
try:

```
  time.sleep(2)

  data = arduino.readline()  #read the data from the arduino

  print data

  pieces = data.split(" ")  #split the data by the tab

  #Here we are going to insert the data into the Database

  try:

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dht11serial (humidity,temperature) VALUES (%s,%s)", (pieces[0],pieces[1]))

    dbConn.commit() #commit the insert

    cursor.close()  #close the cursor
  except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
    print "failed to insert data"
```

## finally:

## cursor.close()  #close just incase it failed

```
except:
  print "Failed to get data from Arduino!"
```

Comment: Are you committing the changes finally?

Comment: Hi, Yes, Tried committing too. But no luck. The issue is once i execute the insert statement it gives back:   <generator object MySQLCursor._execute_iter at 0x03A62D10>

Comment: Attach the whole script

Comment: Please find the entire script in the description.

Comment: @SoumyaranjanMahapatra, did you find a solution ? i am also facing the same issue